# PCB trace length

Tags: pcb-design, parasitic-capacitance

I have some doubts. At the output of my phono preamp there are very big coupling capacitors and i didn't have choice (i think so) - i had to make long traces with output signal. The trace width is 1.4mm, clearance between trace and polygon pour: 0.43mm and the trace length is about 40 mm (4 cm). Isn't it too long? Can it worsen the sound ? Voltage drop and stuff like that is not a problem i believe but some parasitic capacitance may affect the sound. I don't have any intuition so my question is:

when do I know if the trace is too long?

Thanks for the input, cheers!
[image: picture]

Comment: Not answering the question but, how long of a cable you put before and after your preamp? Do you hear a difference if you use a 30cm long cable or a 1m long cable? You can easily find online calculators and compare the capacitance values.

Comment: At audio frequencies, you're not going to notice.

Comment: What is Rout (or Zout) of your preamplifier? That describes the circuit ability to handle load R and C.

Answer (score 3):

I've heard 1-3pF/inch for parasitic capacitance of traces. If you have big capacitors in the circuit, these parasitics will be less than the tolerance of the capacitor. This is usually a factor for high speed circuits e.g. a 500 MHz amplifier becoming unstable by having a few extra pFs of input capacitance.

Another scenario where you may have heard people talk about trace length is at high frequencies when the traces behave like transmission lines. A rule of thumb is if your trace and 1/10 of your shortest signal wavelength are comparable then you have to worry about transmission line effects. For audio, the highest frequency is 20 kHz which corresponds to wavelength of ~15 km and 1/10 of that would be 1.5 km. A 4cm trace should be fine.